# Add a new property to an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a new property to an exercise I want to mark as complete, and I can't get the right shape.

This is the reducer:

```
case COMPLETE_EXERCISE:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.id]: {
          ...[action.payload.completedExercise],
          complete: true
        }
      };
```

I want to add the `complete: true` property to the `completedExercise` object and to get rid of that `0` index object key so that the `Id` prop of the `completedExercises` object contains the `name`, `screenName`, `text` AND the `complete` props, however the closest I could come up to is to put it next to it:

[image]

My current state looks like:

[image: currentstate]

and I want it to look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't wrap `action.payload.completedExercise` in an array

```
case COMPLETE_EXERCISE:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.id]: {
          ...action.payload.completedExercise,
          complete: true
        }
      };
```

Example:

```js
const foo = { a: 1 };
const bar = {
  ...foo,
  b: 2
};

console.log(bar);
```